# Pandas how to count frequencies of patterns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this sample dataframe:

```
ID,Action,Station
01,P,S1
01,R,S2
01,P,S1
01,R,S2
02,P,S2
02,R,S1
02,P,S2
02,R,S1
03,P,S2
03,R,S1
```

My goal is to count patterns of occurrencies in `Action` and `Station` columns such as ordered couples like (P,R) and corresponding `Station` values. So that the resulting dataframe would appear as:

```
S1,S2,2
S2,S1,3
```

So the pattern to find is the (P,R) tuple for each `ID` (`ID` values may be duplicated) and count their frequencies in `Station`.

My attemps so far went to groupby by `Action` and `Station` and get their value counts:

```
g = df.groupby(['Station','ID'])['Action'].size()
```

and get:

```
Station  ID
S1       1     2
         2     2
         3     1
S2       1     2
         2     2
         3     1
Name: Action, dtype: int64
```

but still I cannot take care of the (P,R) tuple and their frequencies.

Comment: do `P,R` in `Action` always appear in consecutive pairs?

Comment: @QuangHoang yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a counter for pairs of rows within each ID. Then merge the P and Rs together by merging with itself, but mapping P - > R and R -> P in one Frame. Drop duplicates as the second row is redundant, then get the size.

*This only works because Each ID has P and R occurring in pairs, one row after the other*

```
df['idx'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount()//2
m = (df.merge(df.assign(Action=df.Action.map({'P': 'R', 'R': 'P'})),
              on=['ID', 'idx', 'Action'], suffixes=['_P', '_R'])
       .drop_duplicates(['ID', 'idx']))

m.groupby(['Station_P', 'Station_R']).size()
```

---

```
Station_P  Station_R
S1         S2           2
S2         S1           3
dtype: int64
```

For reference, `m` looks like

```
   ID Action Station_P  idx Station_R
0   1      P        S1    0        S2
2   1      P        S1    1        S2
4   2      P        S2    0        S1
6   2      P        S2    1        S1
8   3      P        S2    0        S1
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to group `P,R` by `cumsum()`, and use `cumcount`:

```
(df.assign(order=df.Action.eq('P')
                   .groupby(df['ID'])  # this might not be necessary
                   .cumsum())
   .groupby(['ID', 'order'])
   .Station.agg(tuple)
   .groupby('ID').value_counts()
)
```

Output:

```
ID  Station 
1   (S1, S2)    2
2   (S2, S1)    2
3   (S2, S1)    1
Name: Station, dtype: int64
```